# Include an Application Image in Yocto Build

Tags: linux, yocto

I feel like I have done my level best to search for an answer for this but, admittedly, maybe I am not using the correct search keys.

I am building a Linux kernel using Yocto and I can see that adding lines `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` to `local.conf`, followed my the additional images that you want to include is the way that you include things like `connman`, `dropbear`, etc. That's fine.

What I want to do is include an image of the application that I have written. Let's call it `HelloWorld.exe` and I would like it to be tucked into it's own directory (`MyHello`) along with a sub-directory and the sub-directory also contains some files that are necessary for the operation of `HelloWorld`.

I'm sure that there are different ways of doing this but I just need one. I need to know:

1. Where do I position my `HelloWorld.exe` and its attendant files and subdirectories on my Ubuntu system where they will be picked up during the build and included in the image?
2. How do I alter `local.conf` to ensure that the final image will include my application and its support files and directories where I need it to be on the target?

Thank you. Mark

Answer (score 1):

I believe it gets a bit complicated in Yocto:

1. You need to create your [own layer](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.4.2/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#creating-your-own-layer). Let's say `meta-hello`. This folder needs to in the same place as all your other `meta` layers and also where your `poky` directory is.
2. You need to enable that layer in your `bblayers.conf` file. For that you can use `bitbake-layers add-layer /path/to/meta-hello`
3. Now within your `meta-hello` create a recipe in a folder `recipes-hello/hello`
4. your `hello.bb` file is within the above mentioned folder and your can decide to use either `automake`, `makefile` or compile it accordingly using the [Dev Manual Here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.4.2/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#usingpoky-extend-addpkg)
5. Once that is done, in your `BUILD` dir perform `bitbake hello` and this will compile and provide errors if any. Resolve them and once it compiles successfully, add `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " hello"` in the `local.conf` file.

This is one way of doing it. Another one is a bit complex using the [ADT Yocto Workflow](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.4.2/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#application-development-workflow)

Sorry to say there is no easier way around this as Yocto does have a steep learning and development curve.

### Practical Example

- You can look at this blog post by [Boundary Devices](https://boundarydevices.com/what-is-a-yocto-recipe-and-how-can-i-make-one/) which creates a simple `daemonize` automake example. You can find it on GitHub too.

### `devtools` workflow

[Youtube Video by Tim Orling from Intel on devtools workflow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CiD7rB35CRE)

### packing external binaries

For this case use [Binaries Installation in Mega Manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#packaging-externally-produced-binaries)

Comment: let me add an awesome video i found on `devtools` You can use to make really good automated recipes for easy development,

Comment: But beware, that your `helloworld.exe` maybe compiled on a native machine and the hardware machine might have a complete different architecture.

Comment: I am building the application on the target machine. I really don't need (or want) bitbake to do the compile on Ubuntu. I'll give it all the binaries it needs. I just want the recipe to install it.

Comment: @Jethro63 Did you actually figure out a way to your answer? I might have the same stuff (ready made binaries) and want them to be on a board use yocto? Can you write your answer here if you have managed to get things going ?

Comment: Hi Shan: I am still working on it. That and a dozen other things that keep distracting me. But I will post my progress if I ever make any. That example project on git that you referred me to has been helpful.

Comment: Look into this [recipe](https://github.com/SnappyRobotics/meta-apalis-t30/blob/f73fa5a8af226fd5ccafcde3ba1e80fd6e118dcf/recipes-apalis-t30-statics/apalis-t30-statics/apalis-t30-statics.bb) this might exactly what you might want. @Jethro63